CGEvent not working with mouse (macOS 15.1 Sequoia Beta)
So basically I'm making an auto clicker for Mac in Xcode 16.0, but the CGEvent doesn't seem to work. I searched the internet and viewed documentation, but I couldn't find much about it. Here's my code
let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
let mouseLocation = NSEvent.mouseLocation
        
CGEvent.init(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: mouseLocation, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

usleep(100_000)

CGEvent.init(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: mouseLocation, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

I also tried moving the mouse but nothing. I also gave it access to control my computer (in settings > privacy & security > accessibility > my app) as it is required to do everything with mouse and keyboard. But still no.

Is your app sandboxed?

@Willeke no, it's turned off

Which version of macOS are you using?

@Willeke 15.1 Sequoia Beta

Ran into this as well - seems like Sequoia has started validating the timestamp of the event, try constructing the mouse event via CGEvent.mouseEvent (since it does not seem that any of the CGEvent.init signatures allow providing a timestamp) and provide a correct timestamp derived from the system uptime and also a proper event number (even thought seems that only setting a proper timestamp is fine as well). At least that is what solved this for me.

Thank you, what would I do without your answer
